# Add Class in Append new row

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html

```
  $("#btnAdd").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "View.aspx/AddResponsibility",
      data: '{"ClientCode":"' + $("#hfClientCode").val() + '","ResponsibilityCode":"' + $("#txtResponsibility").val() + '"}',
      async: true,
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function (msg) {
        $('#tblRespon > tbody:last').append("<tr><td>" + $("#txtResponsibility").val() + "</td><td>" + $("#txtFullName").val() + "</td><td><a class='delete' id='btnDelete' name='btnDelete' value='" + $("#txtResponsibility").val() + "'>" + "Delete" + "</a></td></tr>");
      },
      error: function (msg) {
        alert(msg.d);
      }
    });
  });
```

I need to add a class to the '< a>' that is a new element I am adding. The way I've attempted above does not appear to be working as the function

```
$(".delete").click(function () {
```

does not fire as it does usually with an element already contained on the page.

Comment: I think you think the last line results in a click event on all elements with class delete. That's not true. It selects all elements with the class delete and then adds the click event. So, it's a matter where you place it. Since the new element is in a asynchronous loop, so should your event-binder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function like this:

```
$("#tblRespon").on("click",".delete",function(){
```

Answer (score 2):

It is because that anchor tag you are injecting to the DOM later. That means wherever you binded your click functionality, it wont have any effect on the newly injected elements.

The solution is to use [jQuery on](http://api.jquery.com/on/). `on` will work for current and futere elements.

Change this

```
$(".delete").click(function () {
   //some code here
})
```

to

```
$(document).on("click",".delete",function () {
  //some code here
})
```

`on` is available from **1.7+** version. If you are using an earlier version, consider using [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Answer (score 0):

If I am correct, you need to reasign the *remove* handler to the added elements:

```
success: function (msg) {
        $('#tblRespon > tbody:last').append("<tr><td>" + $("#txtResponsibility").val() + "</td><td>" + $("#txtFullName").val() + "</td><td><a class='delete' id='btnDelete' name='btnDelete' value='" + $("#txtResponsibility").val() + "'>" + "Delete" + "</a></td></tr>");

        $('.delete').click(function(){
           //your code
        })

},
```

I know that there are better ways, but just need to know that every time you added elements you should registers the handlers for those added elements